# Site over https DynDNS not avaiable

Tags: ssl, apache2, virtualhost, raspbian, dyndns

i got a raspian + apache2 + ssl and dynDNS

The forwarded dyndns works on http, but the site is not avaiable over https and i don't know why...
If i try the same on local net everything seems to work correct. i got a prompt over https to accept the cert.

I think the proplem should be found in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default** resp. **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl**

default:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

        Alias /alias_P1 /var/www/Projekt1
        <Location /alias_P1>
       </Location>

        Alias /alias_P2 /var/www/Projekt2
        <Location /alias_P2>
           DAV On
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "dav"
           AuthUserFile /var/www/Projekt2/pwd.dav
           Require valid-user
       </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

detault-ssl:

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

        Alias /alias_P1 /var/www/Projekt1
        <Location /alias_P1>
       </Location>

        Alias /alias_P2 /var/www/Projekt2
        <Location /alias_P2>
           DAV On
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "dav"
           AuthUserFile /var/www/Projekt2/pwd.dav
           Require valid-user
       </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert-ssl/zertifikat.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert-ssl/zertifikat.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

best regards thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without knowing a little more about your SSL certificate.  Your Apache configurations look fine to me, although I am admittedly not an Apache pro (but I have certainly done my fair share).

My first suspicion would be the certificate - if your certificate includes your IP address, clearly your browser will be upset that the IP in the certificate is not the IP you're connecting to.  That would be my first guess at the problem, but it could be something else.

Where did you get your cert?  What information is included as part of it? Is that SSL vendor supported by your dynamic DNS vendor (dynDNS.com?)?  You're not using a self-signed certificate, are you?

You might check out dnyDNS.com's FAQ [here](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/sslcert.html).  Even if you're not using dynDNS.com's service, this might shed some light.

Separately, if you have openSSL, you can check your certificate to see what information is included in the cert, and check if any of it might be impacted by a dynamic IP address.

`openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout`

You can see a more comprehensive openSSL discussion with many discussion points [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)